# Docker -- restart service if node app crashes

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerized nodejs service which unfortunatly due to 3rd party modules used keeps crashing randomly like once or twice per day. The problem is I need to have that service up all the time. I tried to use the "restart" option in my compose file, but it doesn't do anything.

Is there anything I am doing wrong, or missed in order to restart the docker container if the node process crashes?

Here is my compose snippet

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    depends_on: 
      - postgres

    networks:
      - postgres
    
    restart: always
```

Comment: When you say crash, do you mean the application is still active but hangs indefinitely? If so, that is no reason for docker compose to create a new instance. Only real crashes (as in; the application/container shuts down) would cause this. Can the downtimes be predetermined? If not, and it looks like an API, consider using a throttling application to limit the number of calls and thereby overloading the app.

Comment: the node process gets killed is what I mean. The app is showing an uncaught exception which stops it from using.

Comment: Your config looks fine. Are you sure compose is doing nothing at all? Not even deleting the container? Alternatively, you could opt to replace the "always" with "on-failure" as policy, though it shouldn't matter in your case.

Comment: i tried both on failure on always. Once the node app crashes it just remains stuck at the error exception log but nothing restarts

Comment: Is there something in your image that's somehow keeping a main process alive; for example, are you running the Node application under a process manager like supervisord or pm2, so the "main container process is alive" but the thing you're actually trying to do has failed?

Comment: no I run it plain simple buy running npm start. I dont use nodemon or pm2 or anything like that.